# Combustion and pyrolysis of sulfides and organosulfurs

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, combustion, organosulfur-compounds, pyrolysis

Last week there was a huge fire in french chemical factory Lubrizol, we now know the main products that burnt, to simplify the discussion I extracted a few compounds:

- [isobutyl and isobutene polysulfide](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4839069) 500 tons,
- [dithiophosphoric acid and corresponding zinc salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_dithiophosphate) (R = isopropyl) 200 tons,
- various hydrocarbons (mainly mineral oil) 2000 tons
- as well as  calcium sulfonate and calcium salt of methylphenol sulfide (100 tons), amides/esters of phosphoric acid, polymers, aromatic amines & alcohols, various reaction products of $\ce{P2S5}$ with isopropanol 400 tons

> What kind of sulfur compounds should we expect to be emitted from pyrolysis and combustion of such organosulfur compounds?

Note the authorities claim the smoke analysis didn't show any $\ce{H2S}$ and that the $\ce{SO2}$ level wasn't higher than everyday measurements in cities.

There is a paper on [the pyrolysis of polyethylenesulfide](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ma0116250) showing cyclization leads to a bunch of products, I wonder if it is applicable here  (also I would like to know why no $\ce{H2S}$ is formed?)

[image]

Comment: feel free to add any thoughts on combustion pyrolysis principles

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect $\ce{H2O, CO, CO2}$, and $\ce{SO2}$ to be created during the combustion of these compounds. I'd wager a decent amount of $\ce{SO2}$ was created, but was diluted in the atmosphere.

Regarding $\ce{H2S}$, maybe it was produced, but then reacted according to the following:

$$\ce{H2S + O2 -> SO2 + H2O}$$

Additionally, there were probably a wide variety of odd sulfur compounds, but their existence was transient as they reacted to form $\ce{SO2}$ for instance. Furthermore, the authorities may not even be looking for these more complex molecules.

Comment: I think it is contradictory with their analysis, also $SO_2$ is 2 times heavier than air even if the density is lowered by the high temperature of the fumes. In one of their analysis there is *organosulfur* $<10\mu g/m^3$, same for $SO_2$. I can't make it consistent with those hundred of tons of sulfur that burnt. Where should I search for references showing $SO_2$ is always formed when burning organosulfurs ?

Comment: Also I was wondering if, due to the huge amount of fuels consuming all the $O_2$ in air, it would be more pyrolysis than combustion (it burnt for 12 hours so the temperature was extreme)